# What is a general solution to creating a transparent control?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, controls, transparency

So having looked this up for a while now, I have read probably twenty different implementations but have not yet seen a solid, control-based, framework-based general solution to implementing truly transparent controls that works.

This possibly oversimplified approach doesn't do anything at all and creates a routine (InvalidateEx) that never gets used: http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/248836-need-make-user-control-transparent

This seems to be hinting at what the previous answer was getting at: https://web.archive.org/web/20141227200000/http://bobpowell.net/transcontrols.aspx

however it uses a timer tick to execute the InvalidateEx method.

This appears to be abandoning multi-layered controls and handles all drawing on a single layered panel, while glossing over how the label object appears to be implementing its own transparency: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25048/How-to-Use-Transparent-Images-and-Labels-in-Window

This is a completely non-framework based method: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30135/General-solution-for-transparent-controls

The accepted solution in this answer simply does not work for me: [Transparent Control on Transparent control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874134/transparent-control-on-transparent-control)

The control I get is a generic solid colour (white) with the transparent image drawn over it.

So, I start on my own implementation.

I'd rather not rely on bottom-up GDI drawing, i.e. perform all drawing in the parent-most form, I'd rather not do pre-rendering to transparent bitmaps, I'd rather not inherit from something other than Forms.Control that is performing some clever tricks of its own to short-cut transparency. I really want to get to the bottom of how to draw on a control surface with complete transparency support. Evidently the label control for instance has a full implementation inside itself, how does it work?

Logically, a transparent control cannot rely on simple 1-bit clip regions and needs to stay mostly complete. Multi-layering of controls needs to be handled correctly, i.e. correct drawing order etc. without causing infinite loops.

The first and most common recommendation is this:

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, True)
Me.BackColor = Color.Transparent
```

where the first line I understand is synonymous with

```
Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams As System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams
    Get
        Dim result As System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
        result.ExStyle = result.ExStyle Or WindowsMessages.WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
        Return result
    End Get
End Property
```

Which has very different behaviours depending on which class is being inherited. In the case of Forms.Control, OnPaintBackground chooses to clear the clip rectangle with the parent control's background colour. Not too clever.

Overriding and removing the base OnPaintBackground call causes the control to stay 'dirty' having never overwritten what came below it. Clearing using a transparent colour (optimistic approach) yields a field of black transparent pixels and causes the control to appear completely black.

Logically this makes sense, underlying controls in a bid for efficiency do not redraw the area they anticipate this control with draw over. That area of the form then never gets updated and stays whatever came before the form existed. The painting of a transparent colour onto this is a little confusing, since it implies that the graphics buffer does not even contain the underlying pixels but actual nothings that are replaced with black transparent somethings to make the control appear black.

The first challenge appears to be handling when the control itself redraws, getting all underlying controls to redraw themselves in that region (without automatically invalidating the control itself to start a stack overflow), then painting itself over the underlying and up-to-date pixels. I haven't found a way to do this yet. The closest I have come is through digging around the .net code and finding the ButtonRenderer.DrawParentBackground method. This largely seems to work, though a quick test showed that z order of overlapping components was still not handled correctly, with underlying controls drawing over the top of this control.

The second challenge then is to have the control properly redraw itself when an underlying control changes. By disconnecting the automatic invalidation in challenge one, it makes it difficult to notify the control to invalidate itself and *not* invalidate its parents.

If someone has solved this problem completely, please provide the code, if not, please provide some experience in how I might handle one or several of the problem's parts.

Many thanks.

**Edit:**

It appears the assumed detail about WS_EX_TRANSPARENT as per [WS_EX_TRANSPARENT - What does it actually do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165136/ws-ex-transparent-what-does-it-actually-do)

**Research Update:** ButtonRenderer.DrawParentBackground is actually just used by Control itself, only if Application.EnableVisualStyles() is used and simply forces the background draw of the parent. It appears to be a synonym of

```
InvokePaintBackground(Parent, e.Graphics)
```

Which will reproduce all background drawn details of the parent control.

Comment: look at this article for an explanation on this subject.
http://www.techrepublic.com/article/vb-tips-making-windows-transparent-in-2000-and-xp/5031805

Comment: This appears to be a discussion on full window transparency using windows parameters while potentially providing for pass-through of user events. Specifically I am not looking for 'constant alpha' transparency of a Control element but the ability to vary alpha on the Control, allowing arbitrary shapes and blending to be used and expose underlying components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created the required general transparency control, the solution was a detailed breakdown of the control and all of its siblings in the parent, and preparing a recursive drawing routine on the OnPaintBackground() method relying on the InvokePaint() and InvokePaintBackground() methods. By defining successively smaller clips and intersecting with lower controls, this method minimises drawing overhead.

- The complete control includes a method of detecting and responding to sibling controls' Invalidate methods, efficiently drawing the stack of transparent controls and effectively allowing full alpha channel overlays on animated underlying controls.
- The control can be interleaved with all permutations of child and parent controls while giving visually accurate transparency.
- Hit testing has not been considered in the control.
- This control will not overdraw controls whose drawing is not performed during paint events. This is a big limitation.
- To use the control one simply inherits from the base and overrides the OnPaint method to perform custom drawing. It is also possible to override the OnPaintBackground method so long as a call to the base method is called first.

Finally, if anyone would like the full code including invalidation handling, let me know. If you have a solution to system drawn components let me know that too. Also if you have a more trivial solution that implies I wasted a bunch of time on this, I wouldn't be upset about receiving that either!

[image]

An excerpt of the control on the OnPaintBackground method is presented:

```
''' <summary>
''' Recursively paint all underlying controls in their relevant regions, stacking drawing operations as necessary.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="pevent"></param>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Protected Overrides Sub OnPaintBackground(pevent As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
    'Store clip and transform for reversion
    Dim initialClip As Region = pevent.Graphics.Clip
    Dim initialTransform As Drawing2D.Matrix = pevent.Graphics.Transform

    'Develop list of underlying controls
    Dim submarinedControls As New List(Of Control)
    For Each Control As Control In m_Siblings
        If Control.Visible AndAlso Above(Control) AndAlso Me.ClientRectangle.IntersectsWith(Control.RelativeClientRectangle(Me)) Then submarinedControls.Add(Control)
    Next

    'Prepare clip for parent draw
    Dim parentClip As System.Drawing.Region = New System.Drawing.Region(initialClip.GetRegionData)
    For Each Control As Control In submarinedControls
        parentClip.Exclude(Control.RelativeClientRectangle(Me))
    Next
    pevent.Graphics.Clip = parentClip

    'Evaluate control relationship to parent, temporarily adjusting transformation for parent redraw. This translation must be relative since the incoming graphics may already have a meaningful transform applied.
    Dim translation As Point = Parent.RelationTo(Me)
    pevent.Graphics.Transform = New Drawing2D.Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, initialTransform.OffsetX + translation.X, initialTransform.OffsetY + translation.Y)

    'Fully draw parent background
    InvokePaintBackground(Parent, pevent)
    InvokePaint(Parent, pevent)

    'Reset transform for sibling drawing
    pevent.Graphics.Transform = initialTransform

    'Develop initial clip of submarined siblings
    Dim siblingClip As System.Drawing.Region = New System.Drawing.Region(initialClip.GetRegionData)
    siblingClip.Exclude(parentClip)

    For Each Control As Control In submarinedControls
        'Define relative position of submarined sibling to self
        translation = Control.RelationTo(Me)

        'Define and apply clip *before* transformation
        Dim intersectionClip As New Region(Control.RelativeClientRectangle(Me))
        intersectionClip.Intersect(siblingClip)
        pevent.Graphics.Clip = intersectionClip

        'Apply transformation
        pevent.Graphics.Transform = New Drawing2D.Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, initialTransform.OffsetX + translation.X, initialTransform.OffsetY + translation.Y)

        'Raise sibling control's paint events
        InvokePaintBackground(Control, pevent)
        InvokePaint(Control, pevent)

        'Revert transformation and exclude region
        pevent.Graphics.Transform = initialTransform
        siblingClip.Exclude(intersectionClip)
    Next

    'Revert transform and clip to pre-drawing state
    pevent.Graphics.Transform = initialTransform
    pevent.Graphics.Clip = initialClip
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately I no longer have access to the code base containing my solution. What isn't working in your implementation?

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I already solved my problem with the TranspControl from codeproject.

Comment: Darn, his implementation looks almost identical to mine, except that he's successfully using DrawToBitmap. That is possibly the key to getting the graphics of the underlying control without having to use its own paint methods. Looks like the article you linked is from literally a day after I asked the original question! Thanks for the link.

Comment: Edit: this is the article I was referring to http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26878/Making-Transparent-Controls-No-Flickering

Answer (score 0):

```
Me.Visible = False
```

OR

```
Me.Opacity = 0
```

OR

```
Me.Hide()
```

Comment: I could see how the original question might have been misconstrued. The question is not about how to make a control transparent, but actually about how to implement full alpha channel transparency such that underlying controls may be partially visible through this overlying control and then handle updates gracefully. Thanks though.